# Flask: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, flask

I really tried to solve this error with google, but could not find a solution that works. Maybe one of you has an idea.

My structure is this:

```
app/
 |- static/
 |    |- js/
 |    `- styles/
 |- templates/
 |- app.py
 |- auth.py
 |- db.sqlite
 |- main.py
 |- models.py
 `- requirements.txt
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db.init_app(app)
    return app

app = create_app()
```

models.py:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

As an error i got this one:

```
File "C:\path\Flask_app\app\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import db
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I dont know what to change.
In main.py i got a notice:

```
"db" is not accessed
```

Comment: Try adding an empty `__init__.py` to `app/`. That said, you should maybe read up on how to properly structure a python package again

Comment: After adding an empty __init__.py file i got the same error again. You are right, i should change the structure

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `__init__.py` to mark your project as a proper python package:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── db.sqlite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── js
│   │   └── styles
│   └── templates
└── requirements.txt
```

works with `python -m app.app` or `python app/app.py` from the project root. But still, you likely want a `setup.py` or a `pyproject.toml`, e.g. to actually specify that you want to distribute your `static/` files (and from the looks of it a sqlite-database?) with your package.